# footer div overlaps two other divs

Tags: html, css, footer, overlapping

For some reason, my footer keeps overlapping the two boxes with text that are in different divs above it. I tried everything I can think of, but one way or the other it keeps overlapping when the window is resized. In full screen it does work.
Please tell me how to fix it. I'm kind of lost..

PS: I know that this question probably has asked countless of times, but I really tried a lot already and I cannot seem to figure it out, my apologies.

CSS:

```
*, html, body, div, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, 
h5, h6, pre, form, label, fieldset, input, p, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p{
    font: Arial;
    size: 12;
}


a { 
    color: #2069b4; 
}

a:hover { 
    color: #2a2e36; 
}

div#wholeBody {
    padding: 1% 3.3%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 105%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: eee;
}

div#mainContent {
    border: 5px solid #ff6700;
    padding: 1%;
    width: 96%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

div#twoColumns {
    padding: 1%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div#examplesLeft {
    border: 5px solid #0078ff;
    padding: 1.1%;
    width: 44%;
    left: 0.5%;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: auto;

}

div#contactRight {
    border: 5px solid #ff001a;
    padding: 1.1%;
    width: 44%;
    right: 2.6%;
    float: right;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: auto;
}

div#footer {
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- title and icon -->
        <title>#</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">

        <!-- Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


        <!-- Optimize for mobile devices -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wholeBody">
            <div id="mainContent">
                <h1>Welcome!</h1><br />
                <p>testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestt esttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestte sttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestte sttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestt esttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestt esttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="twoColumns">
                <div id="contactRight">
                    <p>
                        <b class="big">Contact details</b><br /><br />
                        company <br />
                        name <br />
                        Adress: <br />
                        Postal code: <br />
                        City: <br />
                        Country: <br />
                        Email: <a href="mailto:"></a> <br />
                        Phone: <a href="tel:"></a> <br />
                        Skype:  <br />
                        Twitter: <a href="#">#</a> <br />
                        Iban code:  <br />
                        Chamber of Commerce number:
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div id="examplesLeft">
                    <p><b class="big">Examples</b> of published concepts</p>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:float;"></div>
                <div id="footer">
                    <p>&copy; Copyright 2013/2014 </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You two collumns are floated.

You need to clear them.

change

```
<div style="clear:float;"></div>
```

in

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Or, in more classier way use a "clearfix":

Add this to your css

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

and the class clearfix to your parent, like this :

```
        <div id="twoColumns" class="clearfix">
            <div id="contactRight">
            </div>

            <div id="examplesLeft">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That really helped, however, the 'classy' way does not work for me, it keeps overlapping. Does it interpret it differently in the css file or something? In any case, it might look less classy in code, but it works!

Comment: with clearfix method you have to change your markup too (see my answer) . btw you can accept my answer :D

Answer (score 2):

add `clear: both;` to the footer element.

**Explanation**

`clear:both;` means that no floating elements allowed on either the left or the right side, so it doesn't allow the other divs to overlap it.

Comment: It would help if you explain why a little more. Always helps when random users come across your answer ;)

Comment: Ok you're right.
That means that no floating elements allowed on either the left or the right side, so it doesn't allow the other divs to overlap it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the footer rule.

> display: inline-block;

```
div#footer {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using style="clear: both" after div with id examples left. I think that will solve your problem.